# How to print the values from an array return by a json response?

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to print a json array into its values I have the following array after json decode and i need to print it in a loop as it has many items.
For e.g i have to print the value **firstName, lastName** ,how will i print it.

```
stdClass Object ( [content] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 5 [firstName] => Ali [lastName] => S [profilePhotoUrl] => https://prn-spe-images.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/user-profiles/5.jpg [handle] => aliya ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 69 [handle] => hhtc ) ) [last] => 1 [totalPages] => 1 [totalElements] => 2 [numberOfElements] => 2 [first] => 1 [sort] => [size] => 10 [number] => 0 )
```

Sample code i have done :

```
$arrayl = gettviewers($post->id,10);
foreach($arrayl as $valuel) {
  print $value1->content->firstName;
}
```

But it is not printing any value.

**### Full working code from  the below answers: ###**

Helper file:

```
 ####### --- Get live viwers list for each broadcast --- ########
if ( ! function_exists('gettviewers'))
{ 
      function gettviewers($broId,$size){
      $CI =& get_instance();
      $url = API_SERVER.'broadcasts/public/'.$broId.'/top-viewers?size='.$size; 
      $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
      return $json;
      }   
}
```

In the view:

```
$arrayl = gettviewers($post->id, WI_LIVEUSERSIZE);
              foreach($arrayl as $value1) 
                { 
                 print $value1[0][firstName];
                 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreach 'takes' every element of a object or an array. So when you do foreach your `$value1` isn't

```
stdClass Object ( [content] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 5 [firstName] => Ali [lastName] => S [profilePhotoUrl] => https://prn-spe-images.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/user-profiles/5.jpg [handle] => aliya ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 69 [handle] => hhtc ) ) [last] => 1 [totalPages] => 1 [totalElements] => 2 [numberOfElements] => 2 [first] => 1 [sort] => [size] => 10 [number] => 0 )
```

but is

```
[content] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 5 [firstName] => Ali [lastName] => S [profilePhotoUrl] => https://prn-spe-images.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/user-profiles/5.jpg [handle] => aliya ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 69 [handle] => hhtc ) ) [last] => 1 [totalPages] => 1 [totalElements] => 2 [numberOfElements] => 2 [first] => 1 [sort] => [size] => 10 [number] => 0
```

So your `$value1` is already `[content]`. Also you should notice that `[content]` is an array so you have to do

```
$arrayl = gettviewers($post->id,10);
foreach($arrayl as $valuel) {
  print $value1[0]->firstName;
}
```

or use second foreach loop inside the first one.

Comment: thank you @Wolen i printed like this :  print $value1[0][firstName];

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$arrayl = gettviewers($post->id,10);


    if (is_object($arrayl)) {
        // Gets the properties of the given object
        // with get_object_vars function
        $arrayl = get_object_vars($arrayl);
    }

    if (is_array($arrayl)) {
        /*
        * Return array converted to object
        * Using __FUNCTION__ (Magic constant)
        * for recursive call
        */
        $arrayl = array_map(__FUNCTION__, $arrayl);
    }
    else {
        // Return array
        return $arrayl;
    }

var_dump($arrayl) or print_r($arrayl);
```

or

```
 foreach($arrayl as $key=>$val){
     echo $val->content[$key]
    }
```

Comment: why are you setting it to true? he wants to have an stdObject not an array

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

> `json_decode` converts a valid JSON to a stdClass-Object.

Try this:

```
$arrayl = json_decode(gettviewers($post->id, 10));

foreach($arrayl as $value1) 
{
  print $value1->content->firstName;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vural. i already done the  json decode. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

To print json_encoded array do this

```
$array=json_decode($data,true); //data is your json_encoded data

foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
echo $key . ' ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
}
```

or just do

```
print_r($array);
```

after decoding it.

Comment: Thank you for the help Dimi